# Plan with higher cost runs faster

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am trying to reproduce code example from Markus Winand website ([Slow Indexes Part II](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/slow-indexes-part-ii))

Test case:

1. Create a table that is not analyzed and introduce an index that will
   work slower than full table scan.
2. Analyze a query with that index.
3. Turn off index scans.
4. Analyze this query again.

I did this test and database is switching from INDEX SCAN to SEQ SCAN.

BUT looking at actual numbers the SEQ SCAN query is actually slower than index INDEX query.

Why is the planner switching to SEQ SCAN query even when it is more costly and slower to do it?

Here are my results:

```
drop table if exists employees;
CREATE TABLE employees (
   employee_id   bigint         NOT NULL,
   subsidiary_id bigint not null,
   first_name    text NOT NULL,
   last_name     text NOT NULL,
   date_of_birth DATE           NOT NULL,
   phone_number  text NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (subsidiary_id, employee_id)
);

SELECT setseed(0.5);

insert into employees 
select a, 1, random()::text,random()::text, now(), '123123123'
from generate_series(1,200000) as t(a)
union all 
select a, 2, random()::text,random()::text, now(), '123123123'
from generate_series(1,500000) as t(a);

set enable_bitmapscan to false;
explain analyze 
select * 
from employees 
where subsidiary_id = 1 and first_name = '0.550025727134198';
```

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Index Scan using employees_pk on employees  (cost=0.42..8596.82 rows=12 width=116) (actual time=0.024..38.409 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (subsidiary_id = 1)"
"  Filter: (first_name = '0.550025727134198'::text)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 199999"
"Planning time: 0.114 ms"
"Execution time: 38.429 ms"
```

```
analyze employees;

explain analyze 
select * 
from employees 
where subsidiary_id = 1 and first_name = '0.550025727134198';
```

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Seq Scan on employees  (cost=0.00..19142.00 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.017..66.579 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Filter: ((subsidiary_id = 1) AND (first_name = '0.550025727134198'::text))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 699999"
"Planning time: 0.431 ms"
"Execution time: 66.601 ms"
```

```
set enable_seqscan to false;

explain analyze 
select * 
from employees 
where subsidiary_id = 1 and first_name = '0.550025727134198';
```

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Index Scan using employees_pk on employees  (cost=0.42..23697.20 rows=1 width=66) (actual time=0.041..36.159 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (subsidiary_id = 1)"
"  Filter: (first_name = '0.550025727134198'::text)"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 199999"
"Planning time: 0.061 ms"
"Execution time: 36.178 ms"
```

Comment: The condition `subsidiary_id = 1` selects 50% of all rows in the table. For that many rows, using a Seq Scan is usually faster then an index lookup. It is not clear to me if you turned on `enable_bitmapscan` for the second run or not. What is your exact Postgres version ( `select version()`)

Comment: Actually `subsidiary_id = 1`selects 29% of all rows. `enable_bitmapscan` is false I guess, I am executing these statements in one transaction. I also thought that it would be faster, but actual plan for seq scan says the opposite. It takes almost twice the time of index scan.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

Comment: When I swith off seq scans, the index plan shows higher cost then a seq scan. But the actual numbers are still lower. Maybe the cost estimate for single page read and multiple page read is not accurate for my particular system (random_page_cost)?

Answer (score 1):

The planner doesn't calculated with data locality - it expects a reading from disc every time. By default indexes are little bit penalized - if you have enough RAM for file system cache or your IO is not utilized, then you can find more expensive faster queries. But the PostgreSQL planner is configured for utilized disc and low caches - and it is really working. Probably you did tests on server without load. Try to simulate more realistic load on server, and try to repeat your tests.